# Akka stream source - cassandra resultset

Tags: scala, cassandra, akka, akka-stream

If I have a large resultset from a cassandra query.

Is there a way to have this result set as a Source of an Akka-Stream so I can process each row?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/outworkers/phantom

Comment: @GiovanniCaporaletti is there an example of how to do it with phanthom?

Comment: There are examples in some github repos, like this: https://github.com/Tecsisa/reactive-cassandra-phantom
(tip: you can wrap a reactive streams publisher in a source). Sorry I  can't make a proper example but I'm pretty busy

Answer (score 4):

Probably a late answer, but yes, there is a new project [alpakka](https://github.com/akka/alpakka). Cassandra query can be provided as a stream of rows. Take a look at [this documentation](http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/latest/cassandra.html).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this library Cassandra talks
https://github.com/timcharper/cassandra-talks-scala